# How to prevent Curl spam

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing this topic and I hope someone could help me with my problem . Like we all know curl (client url) is a function that help people to send data automaticaly to the server without fill in forms for examples . But spammers do something bad with this method and this is my problem I just received a big spam from curl post (the spammer sent a message to aml users in mywebsite ) because I'm using a normal Id , with auto_increment .
That's why I'm here asking for help If someone can help me I want `user_id` to to be like this in place of `3 = 9j0h8j` (or anything) . If someone know another method to prevent me from auto `Curl` post please tell me and thanks To stackoverflow for this great website.

Comment: What about requiring people to log in to send messages to other users? Is that a possibility?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a Captcha on any form that you submit?  Bots cannot read those and you would prevent the post with an invalid captcha.  For example:  http://www.phpcaptcha.org/

If not using Captcha, then you need to look into different methods to prevent CSRF (Cross Site Request Forging).  Here is a cheat sheet on what it is and some different methods on how to prevent it - https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet and they even make a framework for PHP that generates a unique key for each form, effectively only allowing inputs to come from a form that was rendered on from your site - https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_CSRF_Guard

Comment: No , I thought about captcha but it's not what I'm looking for :'( I want anything else . And thx for you answer

Comment: @ThęKįllēr - added some additional info about what the problem you are facing and different prevention techniques